# Decode serial strings from recorded voltage signal

Tags: python, arduino

I used Arduino (a Teensyduino) to intermittently print strings through Serial. These strings are basically of integers ranging from 1 to 1000,
e.g.

```
Serial1.print('456');
delay(1000);
Serial1.print('999');
```

At the same time, I directly record the voltage output from the serial transmission pin, using some data acquisition system sampling at 30000 Hz. The voltage recording occurs over the span of an hour, where multiple strings are printed at random times during the hour. These strings are printed typically several seconds apart.

I have a recording of the entire voltage signal across an hour, which I will analyse offline in Python. Given this vector of 0-5V values across an hour, how do I detect all occurrences of strings printed, and also decode all the strings from the voltage values? e.g. retrieve '456' and '999' from the example above

Comment: You'll need to give a lot more details about what the `Arduino` sends and what you want your `python` program to do with the data.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "detect and decode." By detect do you mean some equivalent of `Serial.available()`? Could you please share an example of the string produced by the Serial output, and clarify what you want to do with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, if you want to do it from scratch, *you're doing this wrong*.

First thing you need to know is the transmission protocol. If you can transmit whatever you can from the Teensy, then you've got yourself what is called an *oracle* and you've already half way to the goal: start transmitting different bit sequences (0xFF, 0xF0, 0x0F, 0x00) and see what gets transmitted along the line, and how. Since the Teensy is *almost* certainly using straight 9600 8N1, you are now at [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/17562/how-to-read-serial-data-from-oscilloscope) stage exactly (you could reproduce the oscilloscope picture from voltage data if you wanted).

Read those answers, and you'll get the rest of the road to a working Python code that translates voltage spikes to bits and then to characters.

If you *don't* have an oracle, it gets more complicated. My own preference in that case would be to get myself a pliable Teensy all for me and do the first part there. Otherwise, you have to *first* read the post above, then work it backwards looking at data recordings, which will be much more difficult.

In a pinch, in the *oracle* scenario, you could even shoot yourself all codes from '0' to '9' - or from 0x00 to 0xFF, or from '0000' to '9999' if that's what it takes - then use a convolution to match the codes with whatever's on the wire, and that would get you the decoded signal without even knowing what protocol was used (I did it once, and can guarantee that it can be done. It was back in the middle ages and the decoder ran on a 80286, so it took about four or five seconds to decode each character's millisecond-burst using a C program. Nowadays you could do it real time, I guess).